# Getting current element in scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is it possible to get the "current element" inside `scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter`'s filter function?

If, for example, `A[0]` always contained the current element (which doesn't seem to be the case) something like the following might find local maxima

```
def local_max_f(A) :
   return A[0] == A.max()

img = np.random.rand(100).reshape(10,10)
ndimage.generic_filter( img, local_max_f, size=3 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current element should be the element in the centre of `size` (or `A[1]` in your example), but this can't be relied upon at the edges of the input array, and depends on the `mode` for handling array borders.

The [docs instead provide a neat example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html) (adapted for your situation below) for determining the current position in the filter using a class to maintain some state between iterations. This always iterates through the last dimension first; all you should have to do is replace the `result` line with whatever your filter function actually needs to do, in your case this would be something like `result = self._array[self.coordinates] == buffer.max()`.

```
a = arange(12).reshape(3,4)

class fnc_class:
    def __init__(self, _array):
        # store the shape:
        self.shape = _array.shape
        self._array = _array
        # initialize the coordinates:
        self.coordinates = [0] * len(self.shape)

    def filter(self, buffer):
        result = self._array[tuple(self.coordinates)] == buffer.max()
        print self.coordinates
        # calculate the next coordinates:
        axes = range(len(self.shape))
        axes.reverse()
        for jj in axes:
            if self.coordinates[jj] < self.shape[jj] - 1:
                self.coordinates[jj] += 1
                break
            else:
                self.coordinates[jj] = 0
        return result

fnc = fnc_class(a)
generic_filter(a, fnc.filter, footprint = [[1, 0], [0, 1]])
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work.. at least in the 2D case I'm using. There's a problem with the `self._array` lookup. I'm trying now to figure out how to fix it..